# jQuery get the child from a class when there are multiples

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="thread_pane">
    <div class="thread_message">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th class="thread_image">
                    <img src="image" class="actual_image">
                </th>
                <th class="thread_preview">
                    <small class="thread_sender">Father Ted</small><br/>
                    <small class="thread_preview_text">Father: test...</small>
                    <input class="session_id" type="hidden" value="b3a4c17ac149860e9f42624656cdb53c"/>
                </th>
            </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
     <div class="thread_message">
         <table>
             <tr>
                 <th class="thread_image">
                     <img src="image" class="actual_image">
                 </th>
                 <th class="thread_preview">
                     <small class="thread_sender">Chuck Norris</small><br/>
                     <small class="thread_preview_text">Chuck: another test message...</small>
                     <input class="session_id" type="hidden" value="e3ed07c78d16e62df4d4f7efd33a02f4"/>
                  </th>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
  </div>
```

This is generated from PHP and there could potentially be an unlimited amount, and I have the following jQuery to interract with the elements:

```
$(".thread_message").click(function () {
    var session_id = $('.thread_message').find(".session_id").val();
    alert("loading message thread:-" + session_id + "-");
});
```

I'm trying to get this to alert the specific session_id that's displayed in the div that's clicked, not just the first that's found which is currently happening.

Comment: You need to use `$(this)` instead of `$('.thread_message')` in your `var session_id = `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$(this)` instead of `$('.thread_message')`:

```js
$(".thread_message").click(function () {
    var session_id = $(this).find(".session_id").val();
    alert("loading message thread:-" + session_id + "-");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thread_pane">
    <div class="thread_message">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th class="thread_image">
                    <img src="image" class="actual_image">
                </th>
                <th class="thread_preview">
                    <small class="thread_sender">Father Ted</small><br/>
                    <small class="thread_preview_text">Father: test...</small>
                    <input class="session_id" type="hidden" value="b3a4c17ac149860e9f42624656cdb53c"/>
                </th>
            </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
     <div class="thread_message">
         <table>
             <tr>
                 <th class="thread_image">
                     <img src="image" class="actual_image">
                 </th>
                 <th class="thread_preview">
                     <small class="thread_sender">Chuck Norris</small><br/>
                     <small class="thread_preview_text">Chuck: another test message...</small>
                     <input class="session_id" type="hidden" value="e3ed07c78d16e62df4d4f7efd33a02f4"/>
                  </th>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
  </div>
```